# How to shrink APK to make it as small as possible in Flutter?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, apk

I've observed that apps with rather simple functionality are huge in size. What are different ways of optimizing or shrinking the final APK to make it as small as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look to [Reducing app size](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size#reducing-app-size)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, does it not work with --split-per-abi ?

Comment: You can try this: flutter build apk --split-per-abi --obfuscate --split-debug-info=<project-name>/<directory>